# error checking at the controller level making fields required

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a VF page with a lot of fields. the requirement is that all the error messages on the fields need to be listed together at the top of the page and have field level error messages. Currently, we have something like this:

```
<apex:inputField value = 'f1' />
<apex:inputField value = 'f2' />
```

When the user clicks submit, at the controller level,  I check if either of the fields are blank, and if they are, i return an aggregated error. but i don't know how to render the red required bar since all this is happening at the controller level

Basically, the requirement is

1. for the required fields have a red bar
2. if the fields are not filled in, display field level errors
3. For all the field level errors, display a message at the top of the page saying the user needs to enter in these values

Answer (score 1):

You can use (Required="true") attribute. This attribute is of apex:inputField tag. This attribute will give you field level error. you dont need to do coding in controller.

And for all field level errors, you have to add one VF tag `<apex:pagemessages />`. this tag will show you all error messages together.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take it a step further and add errors for business logic rather than just empty fields, take a look at the addError() functionality within APEX code.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling